# format mathematica output a list of results

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a list of expressions that operate on data.

```
Min[data]
Max[data]
Covariance[data, data1]
Mean[data]
GeometricMean[data]
Total[data]
Sum[Log[data[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[data]}]
Sum[(data[[i]])^2, {i, 1, Length[data]}]
```

The output looks like this

```
Out[1]= 1.9
Out[2]= 3.1
....
```

Is it possible to show the result along with its expression? For example

```
Min[data] = 1.9
Max[data] = 3.1
....
```

Any advice on how to format that kind of output for easy reading is welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
$PrePrint = 
  Function[a, 
   Row[{ToExpression[InString[$Line], StandardForm, HoldForm], " = ", 
     a}]];
```

which is fine for small inputs, but perhaps not what you want for multiline inputs.

[image]

(You can turn this off again with `Unset[$PrePrint]`)

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {1, 2, 3, 4};
data1 = {2, 1, 4, 3};

ClearAll[exprShowAndEvaluate];
SetAttributes[exprShowAndEvaluate, {HoldAll, Listable}];
exprShowAndEvaluate[expr_] := Print[HoldForm[expr], "=", expr];

exprShowAndEvaluate[{Min[data],
   Max[data],
   Covariance[data, data1],
   Mean[data],
   GeometricMean[data],
   Total[data],
   Sum[Log[data[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[data]}],
   Sum[(data[[i]])^2, {i, 1, Length[data]}]}];

(* output ==>
```

[image]

```
*)
```

**Update**
In his comment below Usavich, indicated he wants to pass a list of these expressions *assigned to a variable* to the function. This is not directly possible as the expressions evaluate in the process:

```
 expr =
 {
  Min[data], Max[data], Covariance[data, data1], Mean[data],
  GeometricMean[data], Total[data],
  Sum[Log[data[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[data]}],
  Sum[(data[[i]])^2, {i, 1, Length[data]}]
  }

(* Output ==>
  {1, 4, 1, 5/2, 2^(3/4) 3^(1/4), 10, Log[2] + Log[3] + Log[4], 30}
*)
```

You have to `Hold` the expression list before assigning:

```
expr =
 Hold[
  {
   Min[data], Max[data], Covariance[data, data1], Mean[data],
   GeometricMean[data], Total[data],
   Sum[Log[data[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[data]}],
   Sum[(data[[i]])^2, {i, 1, Length[data]}]
   }
  ]
```

[image]

With a new version of exprShowAndEvaluate we can process expr:

```
ClearAll[exprShowAndEvaluate];
exprShowAndEvaluate[expr_Hold] :=
  Module[{tempExpr},
     tempExpr = ReleaseHold[Map[HoldForm, expr, {2}]];
     Print[#1, "=", ReleaseHold[#1]] & /@ tempExpr
   ];
```

The function can now be called with the held list:

```
exprShowAndEvaluate[expr]
```

Results as before.

Comment: Works great, but when assign expressions to a list, it doesn't work anymore. 
    ``expr = {Min[data], Max[data]};``
    ``exprShowAndEvaluate[expr];``

Comment: I think you would have to use `exprShowAndEvaluate[expr = {Min[data], Max[data]}]`.

Comment: @Usavich That's because your list doesn't contain the original expressions anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As a sidebar, you have two functions that can be simplified:

```
Sum[Log[data[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[data]}]
Sum[(data[[i]])^2, {i, 1, Length[data]}]
```

Since version 6, these can be written more concisely and readably:

```
Sum[Log[i], {i, data}]
Sum[i^2, {i, data}]
```